# How would I go about making a button that counts the number of characters put into a text box when clicked in React?

Tags: reactjs

So basically the way I have my code set up right now is a typical counter that increases by one.  I am just using this as the foundation for creating this function. My goal is to make it so the button will add to the count and display the new count based on the number of characters put into the text box, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

My code:

````
class Button extends Component {

    state = {
        count: 0
    }

    increaseCount = () => {
        let newCount = this.state.count + 1
        this.setState({
            count: newCount
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            
            <input type="text" onSubmit={this.increaseCount} />

            <button type="submit" onClick= {this.increaseCount}> Count!: {this.state.count} </button>
        
        </div>
        )
    }
}



// React Only
// it’s own class component

export default Button```
````

Comment: What's the specific problem? If you want to show a count of the number of characters in a text input you'd need to monitor the text input for changes, and on changes, get the number of characters, and update the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the input value into state, and when clicked, retrieve that value from the state, check its length, and add to the current count:

```js
class Button extends React.Component {

    state = {
        count: 0,
        text: '',
    }

    increaseCount = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + this.state.text.length
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            
            <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} />

            <button type="submit" onClick= {this.increaseCount}> Count!: {this.state.count} </button>
        
        </div>
        )
        }
        }
    

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```